# Изменить kubeadm init ip адресс

Tags: google-cloud, devops, kubernetes

Как изменить ip адресс при запуске kubeadm init? Я создал master node на google compute engine и хочу подключить к ней ноды  с aws и azure, но kubeadm использует внутрений ip адресс который видно только из сети google cloud platform. Я пробовал использовать флаг --apiserver-advertise-address=внешний ip, но в этом случае kubeadm init зависат на [init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled. Все фаерволы открыты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот список команд которыми можно решить мою проблему:

```
gcloud compute instances create master --machine-type g1-small --zone europe-west1-d
gcloud compute addresses create myexternalip --region europe-west1
gcloud compute target-pools create kubernetes --region europe-west1
gcloud compute target-pools add-instances kubernetes --instances master --instances-zone europe-west1-d
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create kubernetes-forward --address myexternalip --region europe-west1 --ports 1-65535 --target-pool kubernetes
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe kubernetes-forward
```

Далее просто коннектимся к инстансу master и выполняем:

```
kubeadm init
```

Когда кластер создастся нужно открыть файрволы в GCP и с помощью команды:

```
kubeadm join --token 6edecd.87c0784b88eef1d2 myexternalip:6443 --discovery-token-unsafe-skip-ca-verification
```

можно конектить ноды

**myexternalip** можно узнать через эту команду:

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules describe kubernetes-forward
```